# Analytics report: Where people come from in a certain page?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

In a web project I have some pages with the same menu and such, they all link to the contact page (contact.php) and I'd like to make a report in which I could know where people were when they clicked the contact link. I'm a newbie on Analytics and I've read all about rebound percentage and so, but I think nothing of that helps me in my report.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using the interface.

- Go to Behavior -> Site Content -> All Pages
- In the search box on the right add contact\.php
- Afterwards add Secondary dimension as Previous Page Path

Comment: Worked like a charm, I even made it a custom report for that. Thank you!